# Spring Boot JDBC Transaction Logging settings

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

How do I set the following in Spring Boot JDBC Transaction Logging with yaml file?

`org.springframework.transaction.interceptor` to TRACE level

`org.springframework.transaction.support` to DEBUG level

The following is not working in application.yml

```
org:
  springframework:
    transaction:
      support: DEBUG
      interceptor: TRACE
```

Current Yaml:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      tomcat: INFO
      catalina: INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor: TRACE
    org.springframework.transaction.support: DEBUG
    org.tomcat: INFO
    org.catalina: INFO
```

Comment: one other question, I have this in my current yaml above in updated question, would I just start like this below org? springframework.transaction.interceptor: TRACE

Comment: @mattsmith5 Sorry I don't get your question, `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor` should be in one line if that's what you ask. In general you should not break in the package names, also `org.tomcat: INFO` and `org.catalina: INFO`.